# SImple model works, resulting script doesn't

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, error-999999

The goal is to convert an XY layer (from Excel) into a feature class. The "MakeXY" portion works flawlessly, the arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion portion inevitably returns a 999999 "Table was not found" message. I can build a model and run it and it all works. The exported script, recycled through the Python window, also fails on a 999999. I figure it's got to be an acrpy.env.workspace issue (but may be wrong) and so have added that line to the exported script. Still get the 999999. So what's this newbie doing wrong?

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\\Temp\\MuleDeer\\AllKLM5.gdb"

# Local variables:
X12XY = "X12XY" 
AllKLM5_gdb = "C:\\Temp\\MuleDeer\\AllKLM5.gdb"

# Process: Feature Class to Feature Class
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(X12XY, AllKLM5_gdb, "CDM_9c_FC", "", "Freq \"Freq\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Freq,-1,-1;Date \"Date\" true true false 8 Date 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Date,-1,-1;Time \"Time\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Time,-1,-1;TTF \"TTF\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,TTF,-1,-1;Northing \"Northing\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Northing,-1,-1;Easting \"Easting\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Easting,-1,-1;Zone \"Zone\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Zone,-1,-1;Altitude \"Altitude\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Altitude,-1,-1;Maxsnr \"Maxsnr\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Maxsnr,-1,-1;Hdop \"Hdop\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Hdop,-1,-1;Vdop \"Vdop\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Vdop,-1,-1;Satt \"Satt\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Satt,-1,-1;Fix \"Fix\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Fix,-1,-1;V1 \"V1\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,V1,-1,-1;V2 \"V2\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,V2,-1,-1;T1 \"T1\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,T1,-1,-1;T2 \"T2\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,T2,-1,-1;H1 \"H1\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,H1,-1,-1;H2 \"H2\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,H2,-1,-1;S1 \"S1\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,S1,-1,-1;S2 \"S2\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,S2,-1,-1;S3 \"S3\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,S3,-1,-1;S4 \"S4\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,S4,-1,-1", "")
```

(The fuller script is a bit more elegant in its use of variables, etc. but fails in the same place with the same error.)

= T =

P.S.
   Get Spatial, here's the current script which fails as is. The larger script which creates the XY Layer is also available if you want me to post it but it's a pretty plain vanilla "arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management" call. I continue to wonder if the "X12XY" reference incomplete. I've also tried a string with contents like "C:\Temp\CDM\X12.xlsx" and "C:\Temp\CDM\x12.xlsx\X12XY" with no success.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp\MuleDeer"

# Local variables:
X12XY = r"X12XY"

AllKLM5_gdb = r"C:\Temp\MuleDeer\AllKLM5.gdb"

# Process: Feature Class to Feature Class
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(X12XY, AllKLM5_gdb, "CDM_9c_FC", "", "Freq \"Freq\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Freq,-1,-1;Date \"Date\" true true false 8 Date 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Date,-1,-1;Time \"Time\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Time,-1,-1;TTF \"TTF\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,TTF,-1,-1;Northing \"Northing\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Northing,-1,-1;Easting \"Easting\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Easting,-1,-1;Zone \"Zone\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Zone,-1,-1;Altitude \"Altitude\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Altitude,-1,-1;Maxsnr \"Maxsnr\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Maxsnr,-1,-1;Hdop \"Hdop\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Hdop,-1,-1;Vdop \"Vdop\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Vdop,-1,-1;Satt \"Satt\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Satt,-1,-1;Fix \"Fix\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Fix,-1,-1;V1 \"V1\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,V1,-1,-1;V2 \"V2\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,V2,-1,-1;T1 \"T1\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,T1,-1,-1;T2 \"T2\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,T2,-1,-1;H1 \"H1\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,H1,-1,-1;H2 \"H2\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,H2,-1,-1;S1 \"S1\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,S1,-1,-1;S2 \"S2\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,S2,-1,-1;S3 \"S3\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,S3,-1,-1;S4 \"S4\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,S4,-1,-1", "")
```

P.P.S
Here's the script creating the X12XY object. Works first time, every time. The eventual goal is to batch-process a set of (identical) Excel files into feature classes. The only workbook in the target directory is named XL12.xlsx; the worksheet of interest is labeled "SOB" (Note: The indentation is off as I had to tweak each line manually after pasting it here).

```
import arcpy, os, sys, traceback

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp\CDM"
outPath = r"C:\TEMP\CDM"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Local variables
sWorksheetName = "SOB$"
sProjection = "PROJCS['NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_10N',GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983',DATUM['D_North_American_1983',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['false_easting',500000.0],PARAMETER['false_northing',0.0],PARAMETER['central_meridian',-123.0],PARAMETER['scale_factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['latitude_of_origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]];-5120900 -9998100 10000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;0.001;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision"

# List all files in folder then list all tables in file
fileList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.xlsx")
print 'Listing .xlsx files in workspace'

try:

# Loop through each file
for fileT in fileList:
    fileName = os.path.splitext(fileT)[0]
    sDest = fileName  + "XY"
    sSrc = fileT + "\\" + sWorksheetName
    print fileT + " : " + fileName + " : " + sSrc
      # Toolbox / Data mgt / Layers and Table vuews" 
    arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(sSrc, "Easting", "Northing", sDest, sProjection, "")


except:

tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback Info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n     " +        str(sys.exc_type) + ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"
msgs = "ARCPY ERRORS:\n" + arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n"

arcpy.AddError(msgs)
arcpy.AddError(pymsg)

print msgs
print pymsg

arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages(1))
print arcpy.GetMessages(1)
```

P.P.P.S

Spatial guy, I get the concept of the MakeXY table existing only in memory. Less clear on the datatype issue (love non-typed languages - NOT!). The following code puts it all within the "for" loop yet still fails -- but perhaps for a new reason. The Python output is:
        Listing .xlsx files in workspace

```
    X12.xlsx : X12 : X12.xlsx\SOB$

    Reality check: C:\Temp\MuleDeer\AllKLM5.gdb is there

    X12XY is there 

    About to call FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion()

    ARCPY ERRORS:
    ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
    The table was not found. [X12FC]
    Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).


    PYTHON ERRORS:
    Traceback Info:
      File "<string>", line 42, in <module>

    Error Info:
         <class 'arcgisscripting.ExecuteError'>: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
    The table was not found. [X12FC]
    Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).
```

I'm assuming (dangerous move) that if output feature class does not already exist the FeatureClassToFeatureClass() will create it.  That's sort of the point, isn't it? So am I now battling a syntax error of some sort or just fundamentally unclear about FeatureClassToFeatureClass?

Finally for the night, this system seems happy with the "str(sys.exc_value)" line. Don't ask, don't tell, just keeping my fingers crossed.

```
import arcpy, os, sys, traceback

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp\CDM"
outPath = r"C:\TEMP\CDM"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Local variables

sXColName = "Easting"
sYColName = "Northing"
sWorksheetName = "SOB$"
sProjection = "PROJCS['NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_10N',GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983',DATUM['D_North_American_1983',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['false_easting',500000.0],PARAMETER['false_northing',0.0],PARAMETER['central_meridian',-123.0],PARAMETER['scale_factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['latitude_of_origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]];-5120900 -9998100 10000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;0.001;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision"
sXLSMapping = "Freq \"Freq\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Freq,-1,-1;Date \"Date\" true true false 8 Date 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Date,-1,-1;Time \"Time\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Time,-1,-1;TTF \"TTF\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,TTF,-1,-1;Northing \"Northing\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Northing,-1,-1;Easting \"Easting\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Easting,-1,-1;Zone \"Zone\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Zone,-1,-1;Altitude \"Altitude\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Altitude,-1,-1;Maxsnr \"Maxsnr\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Maxsnr,-1,-1;Hdop \"Hdop\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Hdop,-1,-1;Vdop \"Vdop\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Vdop,-1,-1;Satt \"Satt\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Satt,-1,-1;Fix \"Fix\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Fix,-1,-1;V1 \"V1\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,V1,-1,-1;V2 \"V2\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,V2,-1,-1;T1 \"T1\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,T1,-1,-1;T2 \"T2\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,T2,-1,-1;H1 \"H1\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,H1,-1,-1;H2 \"H2\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,H2,-1,-1;S1 \"S1\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,S1,-1,-1;S2 \"S2\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,S2,-1,-1;S3 \"S3\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,S3,-1,-1;S4 \"S4\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,S4,-1,-1"
sMasterGDB = "C:\\Temp\\MuleDeer\\AllKLM5.gdb"
# List all files in folder then list all tables in file
fileList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.xlsx")
print 'Listing .xlsx files in workspace'

try:

    # Loop through each file
    for fileT in fileList:
        sFileName = os.path.splitext(fileT)[0]
        sDestXY = sFileName + "XY"
        sDestFC = sFileName + "FC"
        sSrc = fileT + "\\" + sWorksheetName
        print fileT + " : " + sFileName + " : " + sSrc

        # out with the old (if any)
        if arcpy.Exists(sDestXY):
            arcpy.Delete_management(sDestXY)

        # out with the old (if any)
        if arcpy.Exists(sDestFC):
            arcpy.Delete_management(sDestFC)

        if arcpy.Exists(sMasterGDB):
            print 'Reality check: ' + sMasterGDB + " is there"

        # Toolbox / Data mgt / Layers and Table views" 
        arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(sSrc, sXColName, sYColName, sDestXY, sProjection, "")

        # Reality check
        if arcpy.Exists(sDestXY):
            print sDestXY + " is there "


        print "About to call FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion()"
        # Toolbox / Conversion / To Geodatabase
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(sDestXY, sMasterGDB, sDestFC, "", sXLSMapping, "")

        del sXColName, sYColName, sWorksheetName, sProjection, sXLSMapping, sMasterGDB
        del fileT, sFileName,  sDestXY, sDestFC, sSrc

except:

    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
    pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback Info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n     " +        str(sys.exc_type) + ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"
    msgs = "ARCPY ERRORS:\n" + arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n"

    arcpy.AddError(msgs)
    arcpy.AddError(pymsg)

    print msgs
    print pymsg

    arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages(1))
    print arcpy.GetMessages(1)
```

Comment: Heads up: you see error 999999, it's usually a syntactic error (ie incorrect path name, invalid field name -- starts with a number, or it's too long, etc.)

Comment: Based on your comment below, I think you need to expand your question with more code and context.  The answer I gave was based on what you included here, so if it is not solving the problem, your question needs to be updated to reflect that.

Comment: Can you post error that you receive?

Comment: Please post the rest of the script.  I am having trouble determining what `x12xy` represents.  Is it an Excel table?  An XY Event theme?  If it is simply an excel table, that might be part of the problem.  Please post the entire script, and also the error text if you can.  At first glance, "X12XY" definitely needs a file extension of some sort, as it cannot just be sitting in the `MuleDeer` directory as is.  ArcGIS has no way to identify the file type.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code, it put it in context which was necessary.  I edited my answer to hopefully fix the problem.  The only place I see an issue is in the Field Mapping of the Featureclass conversion function, but that will throw a different error than you are getting now, so I'd call it progress if it happens!

Comment: Just a thought, but have you tried doing the Featureclass conversion without including the file mapping?  I suggest this as a means of trying the simplest conversion first, get that to work, then add the additional field mapping.

Answer (score 10):

Based on the code you have copied, it looks like your error is arising from how you have entered the file path for your `arcpy.env.workspace` variable.

Here is what you entered

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\\Temp\\MuleDeer\\AllKLM5.gdb"
```

For comparison, here is what you entered for the local variable gdb location:

```
AllKLM5_gdb = "C:\\Temp\\MuleDeer\\AllKLM5.gdb"
```

In both situations, you have doubled the backslash `\\` which escapes it to avoid errors in the script.  This would normally be all you need to do, except in the first instance, you also added the `r` in front of the string, which treats it as a raw string, and performs no conversion of those escape characters.

This means that instead of reading the string as a valid file path,
`"C:\Temp\MuleDeer\AllKLMS.gdb"`

It is reading it exactly as you entered it above
`"C:\\Temp\\MuleDeer\\AllKLMS.gdb"`
which is not a valid file path.

Basically, you need to use either the double backslash `\\` to escape the directory separators, or use the `r` to read it as a `raw` string, but not both at the same time.

-- Hat tip to @Roy for a **very** relevant link:  [Setting paths to data in Python](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000000r000000)

--**EDIT** - **Based on additional information in Question**

As it turns out, the information included above, was probably part of the problem, but is secondary to the larger issue, which is the handling and source of the `X12XY` Variable.

In the original script segment, you are filling that variable with a string of the same name.  You are then passing it to the `arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion` function.  The reason it was throwing an error is because the input to this function is a `FeatureLayer` object, as opposed to a `string`.

Following is a code sample that shows how to correctly call the `FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion` function.  It takes the **Layer** name that you designated as the output of the `MakeXYEventLayer_management` function, and passes that as the **input** `FeatureLayer`.

```
import arcpy, os, sys, traceback

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp\CDM"
outPath = r"C:\TEMP\CDM"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Local variables
sWorksheetName = "SOB$"
sProjection = "PROJCS['NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_10N',GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983',DATUM['D_North_American_1983',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['false_easting',500000.0],PARAMETER['false_northing',0.0],PARAMETER['central_meridian',-123.0],PARAMETER['scale_factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['latitude_of_origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]];-5120900 -9998100 10000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;0.001;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision"

# List all files in folder then list all tables in file
fileList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.xlsx")
print 'Listing .xlsx files in workspace'
try:

#Set Output Geodatabase Variable
    AllKLM5_gdb = r"C:\Temp\MuleDeer\AllKLM5.gdb"


# Loop through each file
    for fileT in fileList:
        fileName = os.path.splitext(fileT)[0]
        sDest = fileName  + "XY"
        sSrc = fileT + "\\" + sWorksheetName
        print fileT + " : " + fileName + " : " + sSrc
        # Toolbox / Data mgt / Layers and Table vuews" 
        arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(sSrc, "Easting", "Northing", sDest, sProjection, "")

        # Process: Feature Class to Feature Class
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(sDest, AllKLM5_gdb, "CDM_9c_FC", "", "Freq \"Freq\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Freq,-1,-1;Date \"Date\" true true false 8 Date 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Date,-1,-1;Time \"Time\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Time,-1,-1;TTF \"TTF\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,TTF,-1,-1;Northing \"Northing\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Northing,-1,-1;Easting \"Easting\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Easting,-1,-1;Zone \"Zone\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Zone,-1,-1;Altitude \"Altitude\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Altitude,-1,-1;Maxsnr \"Maxsnr\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Maxsnr,-1,-1;Hdop \"Hdop\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Hdop,-1,-1;Vdop \"Vdop\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Vdop,-1,-1;Satt \"Satt\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Satt,-1,-1;Fix \"Fix\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,Fix,-1,-1;V1 \"V1\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,V1,-1,-1;V2 \"V2\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,V2,-1,-1;T1 \"T1\" true true false 8 Double 6 15 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,T1,-1,-1;T2 \"T2\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,T2,-1,-1;H1 \"H1\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,H1,-1,-1;H2 \"H2\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,H2,-1,-1;S1 \"S1\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,S1,-1,-1;S2 \"S2\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,S2,-1,-1;S3 \"S3\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,S3,-1,-1;S4 \"S4\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,SOB$_Features,S4,-1,-1", "")
```

When you create the `XYEvent Layer`, the output is a **FeatureLayer**, which is exactly what the `FeatureClass` conversion function needs as the **input**.  This layer is held **in memory**.  It does not exist on disk anywhere, which is why looking for it in the "MuleDeer" directory was throwing the `Not Found` error.

By placing the `FeatureClass` conversion within the `For` loop, it will ensure that each **XYEvent** layer is created and then immediately converted to a **FeatureClass**.

One last note about your script.  In the `except` section, the call to `sys.exc_value` was coming up as being an invalid parameter.  I'm not sure if this is just my installation being old or something, but you might want to watch for it.

Comment: +1 you see this problem pop up a lot. People would do well to glance at [Setting paths to data in Python](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000000r000000).

Comment: Thanks for you input guys, especially the link. Hasn't solved the problem though. I'm wondering now (Duh!) if the "Table no found" is referring to the MakeXY table. In the TOC, it shows as "X12XY" within the layer folder "C:\Temp\CDM\X12.xls". What would be the fully qualified name for that object for use in arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion?

Comment: @Tyla - As I mentioned above, since the problem is still there, and you are asking about something else in your script that may be contributing to the error, it would help if you could post more of your python for us to see.  Would I be correct in guessing that table `X12XY` is actually a worksheet in an Excel Spreadsheet?

Comment: I'll try to make it a new post to this thread as it won't fit as a comment.

Comment: @Tyla - Edit your question and include it there.

Comment: I punted and put is as a "P.S" to the original post.